# How can I save array in SQL DB

Tags: mysql, arrays, string

I want to save a String Array in SQL database, please tell what can be the best way to save it.For now I am first separating all the elements of String array by "-", make it a single string and saving it into a database.

Comment: Its bad practice, but still if you want you can try to save json array.

Comment: Not really enough context to go on...

Comment: I want to save data which is in the form of Array to SQL DB and AFAIK DB doesnt support any type of array so what I am doing is I am converting the whole array to string separated by a comma and thus saving it in the form of String in DB so my question is if at all is there any better way to save the array in SQL DB

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100%, but that's probably the best way. It might be better to separate the values with commas though, as it's more obvious for anyone else who might have to look through your database.

Then, when you need to read the array, grab it from the database and explode it;

```
$array = explode(",", $string_from_database);
```

That'll give you your original list of values.

Edit: This assumes the array values don't have any commas in.